# Where's the bit rate used in MPEG 1 Layer 3?

Tags: mp3

**Situation:** I implemented 3rd party hardware decoder, but it only plays 128 Kbps frames properly; 96K and 160K, while having some sounds from the original, full of hiccups. Looking to the sources I see that decoder does not read bit rate value at all, thus assuming this 128K bit rate.

**Issue:** I am trying to find what I can do about it to make this implementation properly handle 96K streams. Verilog sources are too complicated and intricate, and poor in terms of comments. Thus I decided to look into software implementation.

**Question:** I seem unable to find, and in general unable to understand from info I have, what is the *operational* difference between decoder processing 128 Kbps and 96 Kbps streams. Obvious thing that frame size is different. My guess that it means that for 96K frame size will be smaller, but it should mean there're less subbands, frequency lines or whatever?

I searched for explanation through the internet, and can only find banal explanation why bit-rate is there, excellent article called "MP3 DECODER in Theory and Practice" does not give much insight too.

Where should I look at for this difference in each functional block - in Huffman decoding, and further band processing and final PCM sample construction?

**Update:** My further investigation showed the following

- at the decoder level header's bit rate seems to be only used to identify frame size in order to seek to the next *physical* frame;
- number of frequencies in the Huffman code is not defined by the bit rate, but by the `big_values` and `part2_3_length`, all other higher frequencies are just automatically zeroed by the decoder (and thus less frequencies are coded less size resulting MP3 file has, zero region is not in the coded file).
- and as a result the magic is in values of these abovementioned variables obtained from the side info of the granule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related programming.

Comment: If you can not help me - who can? What is the right place to submit it on SO? I think what I ask is pretty about programming MP3 implementation and its algorithms in overall.

Comment: @Anonymous try using your same account to ask at: [**Sound Design**](https://sound.stackexchange.com/). Sounds to me like your problem is not bit-rate, but something to do with amount of samples decoded per MP3 frame. **MPEG 1 Layer 3** holds **1152** samples per frame. Make sure enough MP3 frames are being decoded to give result of 44100 samples in (decoded) PCM format per second. Otherwise you'll get bad sound like stutters/repeats/echos or even clicks/jumps in the (PCM) sound output

Comment: No. This question is perfectly on topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Can you post an auto example?